# curl pipe script forks a new Terminal window

Tags: bash, sudo, gnome-terminal, su

I have a script which unexplainably forks a new Terminal instance on some Linux distributions... I'd rather it doesn't do this.  Oddly, when I run the script directly (`./install.sh`) the additional Terminal instance doesn't get created.

```
curl qz.sh | bash # warning this will install a Linux Desktop App you may not want :)
```

- On **MacOS Mojave**: Works normally
- On **Ubuntu 22.04**: Works normally in a VM
- On **Fedora 34**:  Works normally in a VM
- On **Ubuntu 20.10**: Reportedly spawns a new terminal
- On **Manjaro XFCE**: Works ok until it reaches the `sudo ...` command in the script and spawns a new Terminal instance

Full source code [here](https://github.com/qzind/qz.sh/blob/ca2b5c06aaafb7569e1d9c41c88e2cdac59f88f2/install.sh).

The code in question is as follows:

```bsh
# Install using unattended techniques: https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/deployment
echo -e "Download successful, beginning the install..."
case $OSTYPE in
    "darwin"*)
        # Assume .pkg (installer) for MacOS
        sudo installer -pkg "$TEMP_FILE" -target /
        ;;
    *)
        # Assume .run (makeself) for others
        if which sudo >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            # use "sudo" if available
            sudo bash "$TEMP_FILE" -- -y
        else
            # fallback to "su -c"
            su root -c "bash '$TEMP_FILE' -- -y"
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Question:  Why does this spawn a new Terminal instance in some environments and how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason a terminal isn't created when running the installer directly is that makeself uses `tty -s` to determine whether it's already running in a terminal or not, see the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/megastep/makeself/blob/e7eb0fda3c08fe113cf0de7bdc08cc6df1157bc0/makeself-header.sh#L567-L589). When running `curl qz.sh | bash` you're opening a pipe that's not there when running the script directly, causing the `tty -s` test to fail.

To prevent the terminal from being opened, you can use makeself's `--nox11` flag, citing the [README](https://github.com/megastep/makeself/blob/e7eb0fda3c08fe113cf0de7bdc08cc6df1157bc0/README.md#usage):

> --nox11 : Disable the automatic spawning of a new terminal in X11.